# OpenStack: how to verify if you are using kvm or just qemu

Tags: openstack

I successfully install OpenStack on real hardware with vitalization enabled, then I configure it to use KVM. However, when I run this command "**nova hypervisor-show node1**" on the compute node it show me this:
**hypervisor_type: qemu**

should it print KVM instead of qemu? and is there any way to make sure I am using KVM not pure qemu.

please note that I used fuel to deploy openstack environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the nova-client.  Because kvm is still within the confines of qemu for openstack, it shows up as qemu whether it is kvm or not.

ref: https://bugs.launchpad.net/nova/+bug/1195361

You can do a ps aux on the node and see if you see a kvm process running.